# Django widget that depends on model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I am pretty new to django and have a question. I got a ModelForm using Widgets. Since I have a field called `discount` which I only want to be editable if the displayed model fullfills some requirements, I make it read-only using a widget entry:

`class Meta:
    widgets = {'discount': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True})}`

Now I want to make it possible to write to this field again, iff the Model (here called Order) has its field type set to integer value 0.

I tried to do so in the html template but failed.
So my next idea is to make the widget somehow dependent to the model it displays, so in kinda pseudocode:

`class Meta:
    widgets = {'discount': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': currentModel.type == 0})}`

Is there a proper way to do something like this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite `__init__` of your model form class to modify the widget:

```
class MyModelForm(...):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        self.fields['discount'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = instance.type == 0
```

Might be worth noting that setting the widget to readonly does not prevent a malicious user to modify the field anyways. Make sure to properly validate on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you define a model instance on the form creation, you have a generic model definition, not a model instance. 
Looks like you may want to change the form behavior after user interaction, to do that you have to use a javascript.